# ImportError: No module named _scproxy

Tags: osx-yosemite, sage

I tried to make Sage from the source but I failed. It seems that the library _scproxy is missing on Yosemite. I haven't found a very helpful aid here on SO and everywhere on the net. If someone can help me. Here is the log :

```
Found local metadata for setuptools-12.4
Found local sources at /Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/upstream/setuptools-12.4.tar.gz
Checksum: 427e916ad99a704af54b7aa3124bd52d4ebf04d3 vs 427e916ad99a704af54b7aa3124bd52d4ebf04d3
setuptools-12.4
====================================================
Setting up build directory for setuptools-12.4
Finished set up
****************************************************
Host system:
Darwin dhcp-147-65-172-203.impa.br 14.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
****************************************************
C compiler: gcc
C compiler version:
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Configured with: ../src/configure --prefix=/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local --with-local-prefix=/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local --with-gmp=/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local --with-mpfr=/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local --with-mpc=/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-libitm --with-build-config=bootstrap-debug --without-isl --without-cloog  
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (GCC) 
****************************************************
patching file setuptools/command/easy_install.py
Hunk #1 succeeded at 1491 (offset 45 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 1529 with fuzz 1 (offset 45 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 1555 (offset 45 lines).
patching file pkg_resources/__init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 21, in <module>
    exec(init_file.read(), command_ns)
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  File "/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local/var/tmp/sage/build/setuptools-12.4/src/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local/var/tmp/sage/build/setuptools-12.4/src/setuptools/extension.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .dist import _get_unpatched
  File "/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local/var/tmp/sage/build/setuptools-12.4/src/setuptools/dist.py", line 16, in <module>
    from setuptools.depends import Require
  File "/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local/var/tmp/sage/build/setuptools-12.4/src/setuptools/depends.py", line 6, in <module>
    from setuptools import compat
  File "/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local/var/tmp/sage/build/setuptools-12.4/src/setuptools/compat.py", line 19, in <module>
    from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
  File "/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local/lib/python/SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 16, in <module>
    import urllib
  File "/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local/lib/python/urllib.py", line 1399, in <module>
    from _scproxy import _get_proxy_settings, _get_proxies
ImportError: No module named _scproxy

real    0m0.113s
user    0m0.059s
sys 0m0.037s
************************************************************************
Error installing package setuptools-12.4
************************************************************************
Please email sage-devel (http://groups.google.com/group/sage-devel)
explaining the problem and including the relevant part of the log file
  /Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/logs/pkgs/setuptools-12.4.log
Describe your computer, operating system, etc.
If you want to try to fix the problem yourself, *don't* just cd to
/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local/var/tmp/sage/build/setuptools-12.4 and type 'make' or whatever is appropriate.
Instead, the following commands setup all environment variables
correctly and load a subshell for you to debug the error:
  (cd '/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/local/var/tmp/sage/build/setuptools-12.4' && '/Users/sam/Downloads/sage-6.7/sage' --sh)
When you are done debugging, you can type "exit" to leave the subshell.
************************************************************************
```

EDIT : Ok I don't know what was going on but I restarted for the beginning the building and this seems to work. I don't have any gcc. When i type `gcc -v`, one answer me that I have clang instead of it ... When i `make`it at the first time, the console asked me to rename my directory `opt/local` because of homebrew. Is think that is what didn't work at the first time. I rename it `opt/local` during the compilation of sage ...

Comment: Sage *should* build on Yosemite, a number of developers have it.  Can we assume you have all the developer tools for Mac OS? (I don't think you would have made it this far without them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is due to a Python build (Sage's Python, that is) that didn't successfully build this module; see [this sage-release thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/sage-release/d7wrbZBZvrI/QtUT295ycVMJ).  In principle http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/17174 should have fixed it (see http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/17169) but perhaps you are using a non-Sage gcc, such as homebrew?  In that event you'll need to either make [that change](http://git.sagemath.org/sage.git/commit/?h=e16d2ae38370fe22f7ade18a8317c3840261a971&id=f62f6c37abbc7dbbfc68a9e8faa7d2e81eb48ca9) somewhere or perhaps to just use Sage's gcc, which you do with `SAGE_INSTALL_GCC=yes` (though that will take longer, of course).  Good luck!

Comment: Yes ! I used `brew install gcc47`. It doesn't change anything. ( i just copy and paste` SAGE_INSTALL_GCC=yes`before running make again). Maybe I should try to re make it since the beginning ?

Comment: Yes, you would have to actually rebuild the Python inside of Sage for anything to happen.  You can do this with `sage -f python` but it's probably easier to just to `make clean && make` along with the Sage gcc.

Comment: PS you'll want to make sure you don't have Fink or Macports in the way, just in case that is part of the problem.

Comment: Yeah this was the problem. Thanks I finally managed to fix it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Awesome!  Don't forget to accept the answer so that if someone else comes with the same question they know it's been solved.  (And enjoy Sage!)